# MathJAX first load within Angular app

Tags: angularjs, mathjax, mathml

I read about something similar in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768295/mathjax-displays-weird-formula-in-div-first-time-it-renders) but I didn't understand how to solve this problem.

I am using MathJAX in an Angular app, but the equation is not rendered properly the first time the page is loaded.

I am loading the library:

```
<script src='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>
```

Then I am using the MathML syntax in my view:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <mrow>
    <mi>Pr</mi>
    <mo form="prefix">{</mo>
    <mfenced open='|' close='|' separators=''>
      <mtable>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <mfrac>
              <mrow><mn>1</mn></mrow>
              <mo>N</mo>
            </mfrac>
            <mstyle displaystyle='true'>
            <munderover>
              <mo>&sum;</mo>
              <mrow>
                <mi>N</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mi></mi>
            </munderover>
            </mstyle>
            <mi>&xi;</mi>
            <mo>&minus;</mo>
            <mi>&mu;</i>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
      </mtable>
    </mfenced>
    <mo>&lt;</mo>
    <mfrac>
      <mrow><mn>3</mn><mi>&sigma;</mi></mrow>
      <msqrt>
        <mo>N</mo>
      </msqrt>
    </mfrac>
    <mo form="postfix">}</mo>
    <mo>&asymp;</mo>
    <mn>99.8%</mn>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

The view is called by ngRoute. So the first time the page is loaded I get:

[image]

Pressing F5 I get:

[image]

Any hint?

Comment: I am dealing with the same thing. using ngRoute and mathml
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">. My equations dont render on Route and they do when I refresh

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.